# iPhone Facebook Application Login Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I am trying to implement Facebook functionality on iPhone using Facebook API. In my application I can open the Login screen, but when I enter Email and password and press "Connect" button there nothing is to be happen. And after sometimes I will be back in my previous screen. I have used FBConnect bundle. I can't understand why I cannot login in Facebook? Even I get that login screen but that connect button cannot do anything.
Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

You need to post your code, so we can see how you have attempted this.

From what you have explained though, it seems like you're not implementing the delegate call back for the login dialogue. You need to implement

```
- (void)session:(FBSession *)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid;
```

and possibly these two methods as well.

```
- (void)dialogDidSucceed:(FBDialog *)dialog;
- (void)dialogDidCancel:(FBDialog *)dialog;
```

They are the call backs your session delegate object will receive when certain actions have been completed.